# Alias a c_char array type to a generic buffer or another ctypes type

Tags: python, ctypes, python-2.6

I'm trying to alias a `c_char` array type to a generic buffer or another `ctypes` type.  But the automatic conversion to `str` seems to thwart me.  I've done this sort of thing successfully with other types, but not `c_char` arrays.

Nothing I can think of or that [seems to be listed in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) seems like it can sneak past that automatic conversion to `str`.  I've tried `byref`, `addressof`, `from_buffer_copy`, `from_param`, `cast` -- but none of them thinks that `.attributename` is a ctypes type.  They all treat it as a `str`.

If there were an `offsetof` function, I suppose I could grudgingly walk from the base of my `Foo` instance to the '`bar`' field.  But none exists that I know of.

```
from ctypes import *

baz_t = c_int * 3
bar_t = c_char * 12
assert(sizeof(baz_t) == sizeof(bar_t))
class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ('hdr', c_int),
            ('bar', bar_t),
            ]

f = Foo(1, '11\x0034')
try:
    fbar_p = addressof(f.bar)
#   ...
except Exception as e:
    print e
try:
    bar = bar_t.from_param(f.bar)
except Exception as e:
    print e

try:
    bar = bar_t.from_buffer_copy(f.bar)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Generates this output:

```
$ ./sampl.py
invalid type
expected c_char_Array_12 instance instead of str
Buffer size too small (2 instead of at least 12 bytes)
```

I don't prefer to use `cffi` and I'd rather avoid creating another `Foo`-like `Structure` in order to alias the whole shebang -- there should be an easier way, right?

In real life, the structure is being created from a third-party header file by `ctypesgen`.  So I can't just create a `Union`.

Comment: You can use `bar_t.from_buffer(f, Foo.bar.offset)`.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  The `offset` member isn't documented, though, is it?  Should I expect that to continue functioning?

Comment: Your question highlights a problem with the way ctypes hacks the `CField` to use the simple string `setfunc`. The `value` setter for a `c_char` array is smart enough to ignore nulls in the string, but the simple setter is for a null-terminated C string. Thus `Foo(1, b'11\x0034')` only sets `f.bar = b'11'`. Instead you have to use `f = Foo(1); bar = bar_t.from_buffer(f, Foo.bar.offset); bar.value = b'11\x0034'`.